# Page`_IsValid is set to true if OnClientClick is set

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I wrote a UserControl that attaches a Javascript function to a form's submit button.  The Javascript function ensures that the page is valid by calling `Page_IsValid` and then proceeds to execute some code. For the problematic pages, the `Page_IsValid` is set to true on first load.  If I don't set the OnClientClick, `Page_IsValid` is correctly set to false on the first load.  I can't figure out why Page_IsValid is behaving this way, since no events are being fired at all.  Also, it only happens on some pages and not others.  It seems this is only happening to pages that have the WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions attached to their onclick events.  Why would simply adding a click event make such a difference?

Here's my code:

Server side:

```
(control as Control).OnClientClick = "disableSubmit(); return false;";
```

Here's the code that gets generated:

Without OnClickEVent:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$wpm$CheckoutPage$ctl02$ContinueButton" 
  id="ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl02_ContinueButton" 
  src="../images/continue.gif" alt="Continue" 
  onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
    &quot;ctl00$wpm$CheckoutPage$ctl02$ContinueButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, 
    &quot;OPC&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
<br /><br />
</td>
```

With OnClickEvent:

```
<tr id="ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl02_trContinue">
   <td valign="top">
       <div id="ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl02_AddressValidationSummary" 
           class="validationSummary" style="color:Red;display:none;"></div>  
   <br />
   <input type="image" name="ctl00$wpm$CheckoutPage$ctl02$ContinueButton" 
   id="ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl02_ContinueButton" src="../images/continue.gif" 
   alt="Continue" onclick="disableSubmit(); 
   return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
   &quot;ctl00$wpm$CheckoutPage$ctl02$ContinueButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, 
   &quot;OPC&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
    <br /><br />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: My eyes :( I'd really like to help you if it would be easier to read...

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
...return false; WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions...
```

in your OnClientClick so WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is never called in your second example.

Comment: Thanks. That certainly can be a problem.  The Validators are now called, but Is_PageValid is still returns true.  Here's my JS:
    function disableSubmit() {
        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            if (Page_IsValid != null && Page_IsValid) {
                return DoSomething();
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return DoSomething();
        }
    }

Why is Is_PageValid set to true?